# vbscript unique filename generation using counter

Tags: vbscript, file-exists

I have a vbscript that generates a file that has six digits and then I want to add 0001, 0002, 0003 onto the end if the file already exists.  I think I am missing something really obvious here as I have put a test file 0000610001.doc on my desktop and my script should popup with a new message saying 0000610002.doc.

```
FolderRoot="c:\users\mozleye\"
Subfolder="desktop"
ClCode="000061"
n=1

filename=FolderRoot & subFolder & "\" & CLCode

'Pad the filename with leading zeros after the client number
Select Case Len(n)
    Case 1
    filename=filename & "000"
    Case 2
    filename=filename & "00"
    Case 3
    filename=filename & "0"
End Select

filename=filename & n & ".doc"
MsgBox(filename)    
'If the file name exists then keep adding 1 to n, regenerating the file name until the file name we
'have generated no longer exists

Do While File objFSO.FileExists(filename)
    MsgBox("Found a match!")
    filename=FolderRoot & subFolder & "\" & CLCode
    Select Case Len(n)
        Case 1
        filename=filename & "000"
        Case 2
        filename=filename & "00"
        Case 3
        filename=filename & "0"
    End Select
    n=n+1
    filename=filename & n & ".doc"
    MsgBox("New filename :" & filename)
Loop

MsgBox("All done")
```

Comment: I am not an Vb expert but if there is no match I would try \\ for the backslash

Answer (score 0):

OK so in the end I reduced the starting counter to zero and then moved the "while" bit next to the the loop to force it to run at least once.  I must admit I still don't completely get why this works and the other version doesn't but I hope this is useful to someone:

```
Do 
    filename=FolderRoot & subFolder & "\" & CLCode
    Select Case Len(n)
        Case 1
            filename=filename & "000"
        Case 2
            filename=filename & "00"
        Case 3
            filename=filename & "0"
    End Select
    n=n+1
    filename=filename & n & ".doc"

Loop While objFSO.FileExists(filename)
```